Server Side Rendering in next.js using app router
I am currently migrating from the pages router to the app router in next.js (version 14.2.13) and don't understand how props can be passed from the server to the client in certain situations with the introduction of server and client components.
I have two files for layout:

/layout.tsx
List item

layout.tsx is a server component that contains some logic for dealing with session, page variables, user access restriction, etc. Basically global variables for all pages inside root.
layoutClient.tsx contains the shared client-side UI for all pages. It looks roughly like this:
export default function LayoutClient({ children, user, page, session }: LayoutProps) {
    return (
        <GlobalEventBusContextProvider>
            <main className="bg-white dark:bg-gray-900 min-h-screen">
                <Menu user={user} page={page} session={session} />
                <Content className="transition-all duration-300 flex min-w-screen w-full h-full overflow-x-scroll">
                    {children}
                </Content>
            </main>
        </GlobalEventBusContextProvider>
    );
}

Here I pass props from layout.tsx (server component) to layoutClient.tsx (client component) without a problem!
Now looking inside layoutClient.tsx I have a Menu.tsx, there are parts that are shared such an icon in the middle. And then there is a part which is custom per page. Here is the menu (roughly):
export default function Menu(props: MenuProps) {
    const pathname = usePathname();
    const pagename = pathname.split('/').pop();

    return (
        <div className="flex w-full flex-row justify-between p-4 bg-white shadow items-center h-16">
            <Space className="w-[45%]" direction="horizontal" size="middle">
                {/* Shared ... */}
            </Space>
            <Link href="/profile">
                {/* Logo... */}
            </Link>
            <div className="w-[45%] h-full flex flex-row justify-between items-center">
                {pagename === 'tenants' ?
                    <TenantsMenu /> :
                    pagename === 'couriers' ?
                        <CouriersMenu/> :
                        pagename === 'translations' ?
                            <TranslationsMenu {...props} /> :
                            pagename === 'logs' ?
                                <LogsMenu /> :
                                <></>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

How can I introduce server components here to render my different Menus with data from the server?
Page-specific menus such as LogsMenu need some data from the server when rendering. For logs specifically, for example, a folder is read where all the logs are stored and all the log file names are sent to the client. This was previously done using getServerSideProps.
I have tried wrapping components such as LogsMenu in a server component to retrieve the server-side-props, but this does not work because Menu and layoutClient are both client components and as far as I can tell one cannot place server components inside a client component. I've seen some workarounds such as here but they are not very straightforward and result in 3 files where before I had 1.
On the other hand, if I read the logs files in layout.tsx it means that I always read the log files independently of which page the user is visiting! This obviously is not very efficient.
I feel like I must be missing something crucial here because I doubt that Next.js would make a release that would be this limiting.
If anyone has any tips or could point at something that I might be missing I would greatly appreciate it.
